# $\phi$ vs $\exists x \phi$. What is difference?

Tags: first-order-logic

What is difference between $\phi$ and $\exists x \phi$
where $\phi $ is a first-order formula. What about satisfability?

Comment: No difference; if $x$ is free in $\phi$, then $\phi$ is satisfiable iff $\exists x \phi$ is.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Don't you mean "isn't free"? To be exact, there is a difference. Just not in terms of satisfiability.

Comment: If $x$ is **not** free : $\phi, \exists x \phi$ and $\forall x \phi$ are all "sematically" equivalent.